# Google Cloud Translate API -Basic

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

Below is one of the python scripts recommended by google to translate text. I am using cloud translation basic version.
I want to convert all the text strings to English but if it encounters an English text string it shouldn't translate and just return the initial text string as output. As per my understanding, first it detects the language and then it passes the text for translation. When this entire loop is completed I get charged per character. But when it detects English, does it translates it back to English or does it just detects and passes the string as it is. And do I get charged in the 2nd case?

```
def translate_text(target: str, text: str) -> dict:
    """Translates text into the target language.

    Target must be an ISO 639-1 language code.
    See https://g.co/cloud/translate/v2/translate-reference#supported_languages
    """
    from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

    translate_client = translate.Client()

    if isinstance(text, bytes):
        text = text.decode("utf-8")

    # Text can also be a sequence of strings, in which case this method
    # will return a sequence of results for each text.
    result = translate_client.translate(text, target_language=target)

    print("Text: {}".format(result["input"]))
    print("Translation: {}".format(result["translatedText"]))
    print("Detected source language: {}".format(result["detectedSourceLanguage"]))

    return result

output = translate_text('en', 'text')
```

the scripts works properly but I how do I ensure that I am not wasting any money to translate English to English or for that matter any language. Like german to german, french to french etc.

Thank You!

Comment: Let me know if your issue is addressed/resolved by following the below answer. I would be happy to help if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

As per the information provided, you are trying to find out the **pricing information** when the **source/target languages are the same**. We have 2 scenarios where the pricing information can be clarified as mentioned below.

**Specified by detect :**

`English(specified by detect)-->English` : In this case, you will call the **language detection api** (**language detection charges occur**) initially and then the detected language (English) is manually assigned as the source language and call the **translate text API**. As the target is also English, we will directly return **400 error (INVALID_ARGUMENT)** and won't translate it, so we won't charge you for translation.

The **specified by detect** means you will call the language detection API initially, then manually assign the detected language as source language when calling the translate text API.

```
Source-->Target : English(specified by detect)-->English
method call : detect, translate
Detection cost : Charged 
Translation cost : Not Charged
```

**Auto-detect :**

`English(auto-detect)-->English` : In this case,  you will directly call **translate text API** without specifying the source language, we will auto detect the source language (English). As the target language is also English, we will directly return the source text as the translated one. In this case, you will only be **charged** for the **language detection**.

The **auto-detect** means you will not specify the source language and directly send the request to translate text API.

```
Source-->Target : English(auto-detect)-->English
method call : translate
Detection cost : Charged 
Translation cost : Not Charged
```

Note that the charging rate of **language detection** and **text translation** is the **same** in **both the scenarios**, so there should be no difference at your end if we only charge for detection or only charge for translation.You can refer to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing#cloud-translation-pricing) for more information.